# Is it a real existing programming language? (What is the name of the code)

Tags: compiler-construction

I have been read a programming book about Compilers.

And there is a kind of thing in compilers such as lexer, parser, etc...

When I was reading a chepter "analyzing syntax", and there is a example that following source code made up of languages I do not know.

```
procedure pa;
begin
if nextsymbol = qa then get_nextsymbol else error
end;

procedure pb;
begin
if nextsymbol = qb then get_nextsymbol else error
end;

procedure PS;
begin
if nextsymbol = qa then begin pa; PA: pb end; else error
end

procedure PA;
begin
case nextsymbol of qa : begin pa; PS end; qb : pb; otherwise : error
end
end

begin
get_nextsymbol;
PS;
if nextsymbol = q$ then accept else error
end
```

What is this language name and how to run or compile to get output?

Is there Anyone who know this language?

Comment: looks like Pascal

Comment: Yup, looks like Pascal; I believe the book you're reading should at some point indicate the language used.